# Multiple background-wrapper in Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, background

How can i have a specific background for, index.php, archive.php and single.php in wordpress?

I tried using a css object on a specific div for every case, but doesn't works because any of the non index.php inherits the home page from index.

I tried multiplebackground manager plugin also, but it changes the background and not the wrapper, the actual background image to the content.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a specific class on your body for each of these pages, why don't you use that (by placing .home in the first place, just in case :P).
A rough example :

```
.home { background: red; }
.single { background: blue; }
.archive { background: green; }
```

Verbosity edit :

As you mentioned, if you have this declared in your CSS:

```
body { background:url(images/body.png); }
```

.. for other pages use ..

```
body.single { background:url(images/body-single.png); }
body.archive { background:url(images/body-archive.png); }
```

.. and so on.

Comment: Well this is my body css object 
body {
 margin:0 auto;
 padding:50px 0px 0px 0px;
 background:url(images/body.png) ;
 font-family:Arial,Tahoma,Century gothic, sans-serif;
 color:#161514;
 font-size:12px;
 }

Comment: I don't get it, could you be more 'verbose' please? :)

Comment: Updated answer in the name of verbosity. :)

Comment: Awesome, super awesome, now i get it hehehe thank you! i'll try it :)